# How do I access Sharepoint list data from a custom spfx webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts, odata

I'm trying to get all list items from a list on the same domain as the client-side spfx web-part. It's a pretty basic call via the REST API, however the information being returned doesn't match that of the list. Rather than receiving the correct column name, it seems that the internal names that Sharepoint uses are being returned.

Example: List column is "Neat_Column", but what's returned in the JSON is a) 'OData__x0074_b56' or b) 'u3b5' or some variation on that.

The code is standard:

```
export interface ISPList {
  Title: string;
  NeatColumn: string;
  super_cool_column: number;
}

let config: SPHttpClientConfiguration = new SPHttpClientConfiguration({
  defaultODataVersion: ODataVersion.v3,
})

_getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
    return this.context.spHttpClient
      .get(
        this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
          `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test_list')/items`,
        config,
        { headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8" } }
      )
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        return response.json();
   })
}
```

The (mostly) full JSON response is:

```
{
   @odata.editLink: "Web/Lists(guid'cf70a11c-875c-48cf-9271-61d305bea952')/Items(1)"
   @odata.id: "8d0c4e10-d8fe-40d0-9351-6f01ab5afe17"
   @odata.type: "#SP.Data.Test_x005f_listListItem"
   GUID: "b19cfc1e-276c-4532-ab9a-a95e18b77cff"
   OData__x0074_b56: "this is also an item!" <---Correct data, incorrect column name
   Title: "test_item_1"
   gvim: 5 <---Correct data, incorrect column name
   u3b5: "this is an item!" <---Correct data, incorrect column name
}
```

I haven't made any custom Sharepoint add-ins, so this could potentially be an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the internal name of these columns.I create a Neat_Column column in my list.

My test code:

```
let currentWebUrl = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl;
let requestUrl = currentWebUrl.concat(`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('test')/items`);
    const requestHeaders: Headers = new Headers();
    requestHeaders.append('accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
    const httpClientOptions: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
        
        headers: requestHeaders
      };
    this.context.spHttpClient.get(requestUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)  
    .then((response) => {  
      if (response.ok) {  
        response.json().then((responseJSON) => {  
            if (responseJSON!=null && responseJSON.value!=null){  
                console.log(responseJSON.value)
            }  
        });  
    }  
    });
```

Test result:

[image]

You could get internal name here:
[image]

Comment: So you created new column?